# Shell Script Variable not working using SED

Tags: shell, sh

I tried all suggestions mentioned in different forum but I am not able to get it to work

```
firstString="/dev_app/Files/"
echo $firstString
String1="/dev_app/"
echo $String1
replacedstring="/dev/app/"
echo $replacedstring
echo $firstring | sed -e "s|${String1}|${replacedstring}|"
```

The above does not work as expected , the same if tried without the variable works as shown below

```
firstString="/dev_app/Files/"
echo $firstString
String1="/dev_app/"
echo $String1
replacedstring="/dev/app/"
echo $replacedstring
echo $firstring | sed -e "s|/dev_app/|/dev/app/|"
```

Comment: `$firstring != $firstString`..... and `$replacedstring != $replacedString`...  Suggest you paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the errors.

Answer (score 1):

because you misspelled firstString as firstring.

Also, learn how to use the -x shell flag for debugging.